# Why is it not possible to create an update script when doing a schema comparison in vs 2010 with a .dbschema file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

This is not a question I believe anyone can really provide a *solution* to, but perhaps someone can shed some light. My actual problem was just solved by our network admin by letting me have access to the sql servers in production, but the problen, as I see it, is still there and I cannot understand **why**.

The problem: if you do a schema comparison in vs 2010 between a database project and a .dbschema file you cannot create an update script.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435(v=vs.100).aspx#ViewDifferences

Quote from MSDN: "If Show Schema Update Script is unavailable, either scripts cannot be generated for the target that you specified or that the comparison needs to be refreshed. For example, if your target schema is a .dbschema file, you cannot create an update script."

The reason I would do this is because I didn't have access to the production servers. This is of course quite common.

So, I created a .dbschema file, compared and I cannot generate an update script. Why is that? It just doesn't make ANY sense whatsoever to just remove that functionality.

Comment: I think you'll be able to do this in more modern versions (Visual Studio 2012 and/or SQL Server Data Tools). Have you tried those tools?

Comment: No, I haven't, but my point is this: why? Why is it not possible to generate an update script from a .dbschema file when making a schema comparison in vs 2010? It just doesn't make any sense, it's like they crippled the functionality for no reason.

Comment: I don't think they crippled it, I think it's just one of the realities of software development. Ship date is x, we have y people, here is the list of features y people can develop by (x - expected QA / regression time). I don't think you're going to get a tangible answer to the "why" question here.